# How to solve this Bitbucket Webhook problem

Tags: linux, jenkins, bitbucket, bitbucket-cloud

everyone!

For context: I have a Linux server in my company with its public access and I am integrating Jenkins with Bitbucket Cloud, I already have everything installed, Jenkins works if I do a manual build from the portal. The problem comes when I create my Webhook in Bitbucket for Jenkins to run automatically. I am receiving the following error that I show you below. I have already configured all the IPs with Outgoing that I have read in the documentation that I have to place them in the whitelist of my firewall, that is done. I don't know what else to do if I'm missing some step, I'm placing the URL wrong, if you can help me please.

My Firewall: FORTINET

This is my webhook URL:

```
 http://<myJenkinsServer>:<PORT>/bitbucket-hook/
```

```
HTTP status: -3

Request time: 16 minutes ago

Headers
X-Cache         MISS from ip-10-18-21-83.us-west-2.compute.internal
Server          squid
Connection  keep-alive
X-Squid-Error   ERR_CONNECT_FAIL 110
Vary            Accept-Language
Mime-Version    1.0
Content-Length  3155
Date            Fri, 08 Sep 2023 21:14:34 GMT
Content-Language    en
Content-Type    text/html;charset=utf-8
Via        1.1 ip-10-18-21-83.us-west-2.compute.internal (squid)
```

I already set the Bitbucket IPs in my firewall whitelist

Comment: `ERR_CONNECT_FAIL` means that it couldn't connect to your webserver. This may be a firewall problem.